# Order Number Problems

Tags: shopping

I think something is wrong with the email I use and for whatever reason i didn't get the email with the order details after I ordered. I quadruple checked that I got the email right before I typed it in but didn't get the email all the same. I would like to track my order but because I did not get the email I do not have the order number.

Comment: This problem should be addressed to LEGO Customer Support: https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwig6vzByLjKAhWKOxQKHexaBlEQjBAIJzAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fservice.lego.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNE9QJG5fJeZsX-vKtdNPx4LaWTWKw&sig2=4oidEl1E-6K6x1Prb2A8VA

Answer (score 2):

**Just to clarify: this forum is manned by Fans of LEGO, not by the LEGO Group themselves.**

That said, LEGO order confirmations sometimes take a little while to arrive (a couple of hours). You can always check your order status online (if you were logged in to [shop.lego.com](http://shop.lego.com) and/or have a VIP account), the US-based Order Status page is [here](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/account/orderStatus.jsp).

Finally, if it's been longer than a day, call LEGO Customer Service. The US number is 1-800-835-4386 (check the [LEGO website](http://www.lego.com) for your local access number if you're not in the US).